# Create a new project with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

Phonegap version 2.4.0 - When i create a new project with the create command.. i get the error "You do not have any android targets setup. Please create at least one target with the .android command".. No clue what that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue and fixed it by installing the Android SDK Platform-tools.

Go to your android-sdk folder and run the SDK Manager (This was located in C:\Program files (x86)\Android\android-sdk for me) and install the Android SDK Platform-tools.

This will put the ADB file in the platform-tool folder that is run when creating a project.